# C++ weird templates/namespaces behavior

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I had a problem compiling my code since it wasn't able to find a matching function on a template. I've narrowed down the problem to this example:

```
namespace cv
{
    class FileNode
    { };

    template<typename _Tp> static inline void operator >> (const FileNode& n, _Tp& value)
    {
        read(n, value, _Tp());
    }

    static inline void read(const FileNode& node, bool& value, bool default_value)
    { }
}

class K
{   };

namespace D
{
    class A
    { };
}

template<class X>
static void read(const cv::FileNode& node, X& x, const X& default_value)
{
    return;
}

using namespace D;
class B
{
    void read(const cv::FileNode& fn)
    {
        A a;
        fn >> a;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { }
```

On Gcc 9.10 I get the following error:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type 'bool&' from expression of type 'D::A'  { read(n, value, _Tp()); }
```

On Visual Studio 2019:

```
Error   C2664    'void cv::read(const cv::FileNode &,bool &,bool)': cannot convert argument 2 from '_Tp' to 'bool &'
```

I've found any of the following changes will make the code compiling:

- `class A` -> `class A : public K`
- Delete `read` specialization for `bool`
- Remove `cv` namespace
- Move the `read` template inside namespace `D`

Unfortunately, none of the previous fixes is applicable to my original problem and I still don't really have an actual understanding on why exactly it's not able to find the `read` template.

Comment: Changing the declaration order might help: https://godbolt.org/z/ibe9DI

Comment: Interesting, that change fixes GCC 9.10 but not Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you think the `read` template **should** be found?  It appears after the caller and is not in the namespace of any associated type for the call.

Comment: It's able to find it if we remove `read(const FileNode& node, bool& value, bool default_value)` so I would expect it to work also when that function is present

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore and an uppercase letter, like `_Tp`, are reserved for the standard library and forbidden for user code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADL strikes back:

in

```
template<typename _Tp> static inline void operator >> (const FileNode& n, _Tp& value)
{
    read(n, value, _Tp());
}
```

`read` is undeclared, so can only be found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

So it will search in namespace associated to `FileNode` (so `cv`), and the ones associated to `_Tp`.

when `_Tp` is `D::A`, it would be namespace `D`.

and the only possible overload of `read` is `cv::read` which take `bool`.

Moving declaration of `read<T>` above `cv::operator >>` solve the issue at it would also be considered with ADL.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11aca05d50ba7da6)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would separate the classes and the namespaces to different .hpp files, which automatically, will force you to make the function:

```
template<typename _Tp> static inline void operator >> (const FileNode& n, _Tp& value)
```

To be declared before the namespaces which use it (like `cv`).

I think that the best way to avoid this kind of problems is to clean your code, and to make it as separate and independent as you can. This way, whenever you want to use this unique `read` function in another namespaces, you won't need to put the new namespaces inside this file, or alternative include all the namespaces that are currently in this file.